# CHANGE vs CALCULATE in Excel VBA Worksheet event - not triggered by formula values updates

Tags: excel, vba, events, excel-formula, vba7

[image]I need to compare two cells: A1 and C1.
If A1 <> C1 Then run some code.

A1's content is a formula dependent cell (from another sheet, same workbook).
C1's content is static, only changing at the end of the macro run.

Issue:
Having an issue with catching Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) and Worksheet_Calculate() event when the cells contents are changed, as a result of formulas coming from other sheets (same workbook): when A1's content is updated (by formula), event CHANGE nor CALCULATE will catch this change.

Unless I directly key-in in the target sheet any changes, those formula-updated-result cells won't trigger those events, hence not being able to run associated macros 1 and 2.

I have checked out some suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+WORKSHEET_CHANGE&s=ceca4078-9061-4cfb-ae34-f57285b98d7d, but couldn't fix it.

Any ideas or suggestions? Higly appreciated.

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Set Target = Range("a1")
    
    Dim my_Target1 As Variant
    Dim my_Target2 As Variant
    
    my_Target1 = Cells(1, 1).Value
    my_Target2 = Cells(1, 3).Value
    
    
       If Not my_Target1 = my_Target2 Then
       
                Call macro1
                MsgBox ("end of update routine")
    
        Else: Call macro2
      End If
    
    
    Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

----- here goes the CALCULATE event code----

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 

Dim my_Target1 As Variant
Dim my_Target2 As Variant

my_Target1 = Cells(1, 1).Value
my_Target2 = Cells(1, 3).Value


   If Not my_Target1 = my_Target2 Then
   
            Call macro1
            MsgBox ("end of update routine")

    Else: Call macro2
  End If


Exit Sub
End Sub
```

NOTE - I have tried 2 different scenarios:
(1) scenario OK (successful), if the formulas are fed by new data that is keyed in directly into the workbook;
(2) scenario KO (not successful), if the formulas are fed by new data that is coming from an online external source;

Comment: A `Calculate` event *will* respond to a formula recalculation but a `Change` event will not - unless you monitor the input cells for the formula instead.

Comment: Hi, Rory.... Indeed, that's what I thought about the CACULATE event.... but it's not catching the change in the formula-result cell A1.

Comment: (I will add the CALCULATE event code to my initial post)...

Comment: Your code is comparing A1 and **C1**, not A1 and A3 (or A1 and A2, as you've stated both in your question).

Comment: thanks, Rory... i've corrected the typo....

Comment: Not clear what your issue is then. Unless you have disabled events, that code **will** run when a formula on its sheet calculates.

Comment: i believe Events are working fine, since when keying in directly in the sheet, changes will trigger event and associated code..... And the code in sheet7, in the structure of VBA Project/ Microsoft Excel Objects/ Sheet7

Comment: Where are the formulas?

Comment: formulas are in cell A1 (source data is coming another sheet, but same workbook).

Comment: On Sheet7? Unless you are changing an input cell to that formula (or it's volatile), it will not be recalculating.

Comment: Sheet7 (in this case) is any blank sheet which I am using as a control sheet: i get my control data here and based on their changing values, it should trigger the Calculate event...

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Is the formula on sheet7 and are you doing something to make that formula recalculate? If not, the `Calculate` event will not fire.

Comment: yes, formula is in sheet7, but data is on another sheet. I have tried in a blank workbook, and it works fine....

Comment: Could you share the formula in `Sheet7.Range("A1")`?

Comment: Hi, VBasic2008. The formula is :  @APIGetVariable(param1; param2; param3)

It works fine: values are seemlessly updated in the destination cell A1 anytime there is a chage in the datasource (external to this workbook) but, again, this update will not trigger the Calculate event.

Comment: What kind of function is that? It's not an Excel one, which means you may need to use something like SetLinkOnData to run a macro in response to it, or go back to using a Change event to monitor the input cells for changes.

Comment: It's a (external) Database API function (part of an SAP addin for Excel), linking Excel to Sap external online datasources

Comment: i could capture the event with the Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _ 
 ByVal Source As Range)

Answer (score 0):

i could capture the event with the Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _ ByVal Source As Range)

- thank you all for your help.